# how to evaluate the values of an object using javascript for in statement and return with formatting

Tags: javascript

How would I use the javascript for in statement to iterate over properties of an object and if the value of a property is an empty string or null then return "property a = 'empty string' is bad", "property b = 'something' is good", "property c = 'null' is bad" in the console. 
In the end I want to return property plus the value from an object that are bad and those that are good like the below example.

example output on page:
 - a = empty string "color:red"
 - b = something "color:green"
 - c = null "color:red"

```js
var string1 = "";
var object1 = {a: "", b: "something", c: null};

for (var property1 in object1) {
  string1 += object1[property1];
}

console.log(string1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var object1 = {a: "", b: "something", c: null};

var objectKeys = Object.keys(object1);

for(var i = 0;i < objectKeys.length;i++)
{
  var propName = objectKeys[i];
  var propVal = object1[propName];

  console.log("property: " + propName);
  console.log("value: " + propVal);
}
```

From there you can add logic to determine how you build your string.